# Getting all data from result of search in MYSQL sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi everyone I have multiples tables which I want to get tables with specific column name which I am able with the following code:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS 'ColumnName'
    ,TABLE_NAME AS 'TableName'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASENAME'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%columnName_I_Need%' // Example not actual search
ORDER BY TableName
    ,ColumnName;
```

Now I want to get the all data from the resulted tables.
For example, get all columns and their data in resulted tables.
This is an example but is not working :

```
SELECT * WHERE columnName_I_Need = 1
```

Is this possible with MySQL?
MySQL version: `5.5.5-10.3.23 MariaDB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite complicated.  If you used only dynamic SQL, you would need a looping mechanism.  My recommendation is to generate the SQL and then run it manually:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', TABLE_NAME,
                    ' WHERE ', COLUMN_NAME, ' = 1'
                    SEPARATOR '; 
'
                   )
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASENAME' AND
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%columnName_I_Need%';
```

Then copy the statement and run it manually.

Comment: Well I thought it would be quite complicated. 
But your suggestion makes my life easier.
Thank you I will upvote and try to accept it as answer.
PS: Couldnt up vote but accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and basic query to access the data from the table.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename
```

`WHERE` can include a condition here.

`*` is used to select each and every column.

One can use the column name to access a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

The 'FROM' is missing in your query. Also when you specify a column name it should be written inside single quotes.

```
    SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE columnName_you_Need = 'colum_id'
```